# The getter 'params' isn't defined for the type "GoRouterState" Flutter

Tags: flutter, getter, flutter-go-router

I am trying to resolve the issue with getter, error message:

> The getter 'params' isn't defined for the type 'GoRouterState'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'params', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'params'.

My main.dart code looks following way:

```
                      GoRoute(
                path: 'session/:level',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  final levelNumber = int.parse(state.params['level']!);
                  final level = gameLevels
                      .singleWhere((e) => e.number == levelNumber);
                  return buildMyTransition<void>(
                    child: PlaySessionScreen(
                      level,
                      key: const Key('play session'),
                    ),
                    color: context.watch<Palette>().backgroundPlaySession,
                  );
                },
              ),
```

GoRouterState is defined in another file:

```
    class ProductCategoryList extends StatelessWidget {
    const ProductCategoryList({super.key});
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoRouterState state = GoRouterState.of(context);
    final Category category = Category.values.firstWhere(
    (Category value) => value.toString().contains(state.params['category']!),
    orElse: () => Category.all,
    );
    final List<Widget> children = ProductsRepository.loadProducts(category: category)
    .map<Widget>((Product p) => RowItem(product: p))
    .toList();
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Styles.scaffoldBackground,
    body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text(getCategoryTitle(category), style: Styles.productListTitle),
        backgroundColor: Styles.scaffoldAppBarBackground,
        pinned: true,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(children),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On version [7.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#700) contains some breaking changes including `params`.

> `params` and `queryParams` in BuildContext's namedLocation, pushNamed, pushReplacementNamed replaceNamed have been renamed to `pathParameters` and `queryParameters`.

For your case, it will be

```
final levelNumber = int.parse(state.pathParameters['level']!); //better to do a null check
```

Comment: saved my time JazakalAllah

Answer (score 6):

From version [10.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#1000) the `queryParameters`, and `queryParametersAll` also updated.

To solve that you can use: `dart fix --apply` or manual update:

From:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final String location = GoRouterState.of(context).location;
  final Map<String, String> queryParameters = GoRouterState.of(context).queryParameters;
  final Map<String, List<String>> queryParametersAll = GoRouterState.of(context).queryParametersAll;
}
```

To:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final String location = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString();
  final Map<String, String> queryParameters = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.queryParameters;
  final Map<String, List<String>> queryParametersAll = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.queryParametersAll;
}
```