# go_router flutter params not available. not able access the params variable

Tags: flutter

I was using go_router for the Routing in the flutter but i am not able to access the params of the goRouterState
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfgeZ.png)

Comment: Which go_router version you're using?

Comment: go_router: 8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452471/16013955

in go router the names of the parameters have been changed to something like this:

```
old: params , new: pathParamaters
old: queryParams , new: queryParameters
```